# Issue in making rest call which actually works fine locally but not in production server

Tags: java

In my java code I'm calling third pary apis. In my local workspace it works pretty well and I'm getting proper response. But When I deploy the war in production, I see in logs, I'm calling the apis and didn't get any response. It sound wierd to me and got stuck with it. Please find the snippet and I'm completely calling api in plain old Java.

```
private void updateRetailerOrderStatus(String trackingId) {
       CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
 try {

     System.out.println("Inside updateRetailerOrderStatus By Android");
       Order order = orderDao.getOrdersByTrackingId(trackingId);

     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://SomeDomine/v1/order/delivered");
     httpPost.addHeader("Some Key", "Some Value");
     httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
     json.put("awb_no", order.getTrackingId());
     json.put("order_no", order.getOrderId());         
     json.put("delivered_date", order.getDeliveredDate().toString());
     json.put("status", "delivered");
     json.put("carrier", "Delivery");


     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
     httpPost.setEntity(entity);

     System.out.println(json.toString());

     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
     BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));           
     StringBuffer respBuffer = new StringBuffer();
     String line = "";
     while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {           
        System.out.println(line);
        respBuffer.append(line);
     }

     System.out.println("API Response: "+ respBuffer.toString());

 } catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println("Error in fetchToken :"+  ex.getMessage());
       System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
 } finally {
       try {
              httpclient.close();
       } catch(Exception ex) {
              System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
 }
}
```

My Questions are:
1) Is there a possibility of happening this? If So, Why?
2) Should I call this in saparate thread? But, I didn't see any suggestions of doing it in most of the examples.

Comment: Separate thread is just an optimisation which I don't think applies here. Not getting response when calling the api, then there should be something, stack trace,  http response code and logs will help.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj After making call, I'm not getting any  acknowledgement, not even status code. I've deployed app in one of the Aws instances

Comment: Not sure,  connection or request was supposed to time out atleast. Can you do a wet on the url to see the behavior?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Didn't help either

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I've set the logs and what I could see is control is going till the JsonObject creation but not from then. And there is no issues in getters getting data. Locally it's working smooth.